# What is the list that is being built by this code?

Tags: c, list, singly-linked-list

Can someone tell me what the exact list is that is being built by this program?  (the program does not run, which is fine).  Also, any lines of code that you can be pointed out to me that pertain to making the list would greatly be appreciated, I'm having trouble tracing this program.

all I seem to see is that it seems to be a linked list of nodes with the data from 'values'? I don't know though though, just lost.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include "sNode.h"

    int main()
    {
       int i;
       int rV = 0;
       List l = NULL;
       char* input[] = { "06", "24", "3" };
       sNode *s, *t;

       for( i=0; i<3; ++i )
       {
          t = (sNode*)malloc( sizeof( sNode ));
          if( t == NULL )
          {
             fprintf( stderr, "Couldn't get memory for a node!  Exiting." );
             rV = 1;
             break;
          }
          t->data = input[i];
          t->next = l;
          l = t;
       }


       s = l;
       while( s != NULL )
       {
          t = s->next;
          free( s );
          s = t;
       }

       return rV;
}
```

Comment: You should post your whole code, including all the `#includes` and the definitions of things like `sNode` and `List`.  Also, it would be good to show that you actually attempted to understand the code yourself.  Explain your thought process and where you got stuck so we can help you get to the next step.

Comment: My apologies... it has since been edited..  Also, all I seem to see is that it seems to be a linked list of nodes with the data from 'values'?  I don't know though though, just lost.

Comment: `the program does not run` Then, by definition, it doesn't build any list either. `I'm having trouble tracing this program` What kind of trouble? What, specifically, seems to be the problem?

Comment: @DtownDom You forgot the last closing brace.:) It is a single-linked kist. Each node has two data members: the first one of type char * (char *data;) and the second one of type sNode * (sNode *next; ). What is not clear?

Comment: This is my first time looking at linked-lists, nodes, etc..  a lot of this code was brand new to me.  I did not write the code and was not trying to get the code to run, I was only trying to understand what the original author was trying to do (I could tell they were trying to make a list, but that was about all I could figure out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

l is pointing to the head of a linked list.
So l is assigned NULL to start with, i.e. empty linked list.

In the first iteration of the for-loop a node is created and assigned the value "06". l is set to point to the newly created node. So you have:

l ---> ("06", NULL)

In the second iteration of the for-loop a node is created and assigned the value "24". l is set to point to the newly created node. So you have:

l ---> ("24", next=---)---> ("06", next=NULL)

In the third iteration of the for-loop a node is created and assigned the value "3". l is set to point to the newly created node. So you have:

l ---> ("3", next=---)---> ("24", next=---)---> ("06", next=NULL)

The the end you have a linked list where elements are inserted in the front.

Answer (score 0):

**How to trace objects of a program**

Here we are looking at `l` because it is of type `List`, the object in question. The lines where `l` is altered are

```
int main()
{
        List l = NULL;
        for( i=0; i<3; ++i )
        {
                l = t;
        }
}
```

It appears that `t` is being assigned to `l` so we look at `t`:

```
int main()
{
    List l = NULL;
    sNode *s, *t;

    for( i=0; i<3; ++i )
    {
            t = (sNode*)malloc( sizeof( sNode ));
            if( t == NULL )
            {
                    fprintf( stderr, "Couldn't get memory for a node!  Exiting." );
                    rV = 1;
                    break;
            }
            t->data = input[i];
            t->next = l;
            l = t;
    }
    while( s != NULL )
    {
            t = s->next;
    }
```

Now it is more clear what is happening. `malloc` is allocating dynamic memory the size of `sNode` for the address of `t`. According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/next/, `t->next` points to the next element (it's being re-assigned to `l` via `t->next = l`. Continue doing this; **Hint** you look at `s` next since `s` is being altered. It appears that member data of `t` is being re-assigned, specifically it now equals input at `&input + sizeof(i)`.